# Download function doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, http-headers, download

I have a problem with a download function. 
At my system, i like to make a secure download. 
Files at my root are not accessible trough the url.
I set the ftp rights un 700. Only the server can acces.
After that i made a function that can download the file for the user.
At that point i can make with session a security check.

But when the servers downloads the file trought this code, the file opens in the browser.
With a exe, the browser show strange letters.

```
  // Bestandsnaam
            $file = 'bestanden/test.exe';

            // Ophalen bestand
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($file);
                exit;
            }
```

I want a save as box when users acces the url.

I want to use this function this way:

```
<a href="www.site.nl/downloadfunction/file">download</a>
```

Does anybody has a solution. I tried Javascript `document.execCommand('SaveAs',null,bestand);` in stead of readfile 
But it doen;t work in Firefox.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do u have a else part for this function ? Also check whether the path of the file is correct and the file has the permission to be fetched.

Comment: `readfile` is PHP, `execCommand` is JavaScript. You can't just swap them directly. Also `execCommand('save'` is IE only so that would not be a very good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting `ob_clean` above the headers. If those headers are succesfully sent in your current code, I even doubt whether you need ob_clean.

Answer (score 2):

You could have some chars in the output before the headers functions because the code seems correct. In that case you should also have the `error_display` set to off because otherwise you should receive a warning.

Check for that with [headers_sent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) function just after the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [download helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html):

```
function process($file)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $data = file_get_contents("my-downloads/$file"); // Read the file's contents
    force_download($file, $data);            
}
```

Should take care of the details (headers, mime-type detection) you would otherwise need to fiddle with.

The [source is available](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/ff390b9c43f33ee734b5e8abc754539799a19357/system/helpers/download_helper.php#L42) if you're interested in the details.

Comment: without additionally specify other HTTP header, you will get an "unknown-format" attachment.

Comment: @toopay: The download helper takes care of that.

Comment: without additionally specify other HTTP header and validate the file existence, you will get an "unknown-format" attachment.

Comment: Well if you open non-existant files, this is obvious from the code. Regarding the file extension, you should configure your codeigniter mime-types in case it's not already in. Ohterwise it will be offered as a binary file which is normally fine.

Comment: I'm actually aggree to use download helper, which actually make it simpler (with notice that they should ensure the mime-types is there, in their mimes.php/config folder). But at least provide a simple validation in your above code. Or you will give him another problem instead a "smarter" solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use the exact same code and it works perfectly.

However, what the client do depends on the browser parameters. If the file type is set to "always open" in your browser, and the default download action is "download without asking" it will 1) download the file in your default download folder and 2) open it. You simply need to check the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" to have the box.

Comment: Hmm, problem solved. The file was corrupt. Very strange problem. Thanks for your help!